# taking request user on Models.py DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

Thanks for your time:
I've got a model(Pets) that has a foreign key to other (People) and people has a OnetoOne (User).

I'm trying to call the errors on a ModelForm doing the clean method on Models.py. although the foreign key field of Pets is set to be the request.user.person (reversed OneToOne field of User with People). When i try to save the form i get the error:

models.py:

```
class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='person')
    birthday = models.DateField()
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.user)


class Pets(models.Model):
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='peop')
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    custo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    tipo = models.SmallIntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.pessoa, self.nome)


    def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
        super().clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
        slug = slugify(self.pessoa)
        if slug.startswith('a') and self.tipo == 2:
            if exclude and 'pessoa' in exclude:
                raise ValidationError('pessoas com a nao podem ter gatos')
```

views.py:

```
def create_pet_form3(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PetForm5(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pet = form.save(commit=False)
            pet.pessoa = request.user.person
            pet.save()
        else:
            raise ValidationError('corriga os erros')
    else:
        form = PetForm5()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'petform2.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
class PetForm5(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        prefix = 'pet'
        model = Pets
        fields = ['nome', 'custo', 'tipo']
        exclude = ['pessoa']
```

Comment: You didn't add the error that you have got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needs to be assigned from People, something like

```
pet.pessoa = People.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Comment: module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'user'

Comment: i can assign like this in views but on mothels ain't working

Comment: you have to be logged in. User is in django.contrib.auth

Comment: i'm trying logged in. i get the user like 
User = get_user_model()

Comment: couldn't you use instance.username?

Comment: pet.pessoa = instance.username 
or
pet.pessoa = People.objects.get(user = instance.username)       both cases i get undefined variable on instance

Comment: i guess the reason is when i'm in the models.py i can't use the request or instance and the validation comes before to the form.is_valid() on views.py/// So i can't set the Pets.pessoa before calling form.is_valid() because the form validation takes the Pets.pessoa to validate other fields

Answer (score 0):

you should assign the user from People class

```
pet.pessoa = People.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Comment: i get:

module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'user'

Comment: user can be available if logged in

Comment: i'm logging in before trying to create the pet

Comment: i can assign like this in views but on mothels ain't working